# Can we set style to title tag in header

Tags: html, css, title

Can we set style to title tag in header in html head as the following. I tried it did not work..

```
<title style="font-style:italic;"> My Title</title>
```

Comment: I just came across a curious page behaviour in Chrome in my company's intranet (so cannot share). [![Title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJALM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJALM.png)
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDUDX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDUDX.png) It seems the two special signs after "future" affect the font rendering even in the tab title. Is this a bug?

Comment: I just noticed that https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript page title has a monospaced font... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejl8H.png

Comment: I googled and googled but until I added 15 keywords.. "Set font-family for web page tab title text (as seen on reddit.com/r/javascript)" I finally found this thread.

Comment: This is a duplicate SO thread asking the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579477/can-i-give-a-title-tag-a-color-and-different-font

Comment: I looked through all the <meta> tags in the <head> of this reddit page but didn't see anything. Tried setting font-family css on the <title> tag, also nothing.

Comment: "Google Chrome is up to date - Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I give a title tag a color and different font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579477/can-i-give-a-title-tag-a-color-and-different-font)

Comment: I'm not sure how, but it can be done: Chrome, Waterfox, and Firefox: [Title attribute with styled text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqIfM.png) og:title ℛ on Twitter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can apply CSS to the `<title>` element, but not though the `style` attribute (since it is for "[All elements but BASE, BASEFONT, HEAD, HTML, META, PARAM, SCRIPT, STYLE, TITLE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html)").

I'm not aware of any browser that will apply CSS for the rendering of the title in browser tabs or title bars though.

You can, however, do something like:

```
head { display: block; }
title { display: block; font-size: 200%; font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: I guess Firefox has some XUL-related business going on that *might* involve CSS specific to its chrome, but that's probably waaaaaaaaay out of everyone's league...

Answer (score 3):

Nope. How the title is rendered is up to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the title is shown in the browser title bar and NOT on the page where styles get applied, so event if you set style on title tag, it wont have any effect

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the title (`<title>`) tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS rule:

```
* {display:block}
```

On my Chrome browser, this makes the `title` (and `script` elements!) visible on the page. Still I don't think you want that. Normally we use `h1` .. `h6` for titles that need to be visible on the page itself.

Comment: Not saying i need points for this answer, but I do think it is quitte interesting to see that an answer showing that it can be done (which it can) gets negative points when answers saying it is not possible (when in fact, it is) score positive...

Comment: Is this a bug or a feature? Still, deserves an upvote.

Comment: The OP is pretty clearly asking about styling the actual display of the title in the browser tab, not on the page itself.

Comment: I beg to differ about 'clearly saying' but ok.... still think this is an interesting little style rule nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

You can't set style to title tag I had before also tried it. However you can style console (You can use two attributes in `console.log`).

For example, I log text `WARNING!` This website is not safe!" and style it I can do this:

```
console.log("%cWARNING! This website is not safe!%c", "font-color: red; font-weight: bold");
```

If I change the places of `%c` it will show text from the first `%c` to second `%c` into style.