# Page title CSS style

Tags: css

Is it possible to change title font style?

I want to have my page title with `font-variant: small-caps;`

Comment: If there is it would certainly not be anything that would be reliably portable.

Comment: i don't think we can style title tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we set style to title tag in header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649610/can-we-set-style-to-title-tag-in-header)

Answer (score 7):

No we cant style it. For some information you can read [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html) about the title tag. It says:

> The title is not part of the text of the document, but is a property
>   of the whole document. **It may not contain anchors, paragraph marks, or
>   highlighting**. The title may be used to identify the node in a history
>   list, to label the window displaying the node, etc. It is not normally
>   displayed in the text of a document itself. Contrast titles with
>   headings . The title should ideally be less than 64 characters in
>   length. That is, many applications will display document titles in
>   window titles, menus, etc where there is only limited room. Whilst
>   there is no limit on the length of a title (as it may be automatically
>   generated from other data), information providers are warned that it
>   may be truncated if long.