# Can I give a title tag a color and different font?

Tags: css, html, tags, title

I was wondering if there is a way to give a page title a different color and font in the page tab. Something like:

```
title{ color: red; font: 12px tahoma;}
```

Just thought it would be fun to add into sites. I tried the above and it didn't work in my CSS file. Also tried giving it a `class="title"`giving it a CSS style of `.title{ color: red; font: 12px tahoma;}` but that didn't work either.

Comment: linking back to duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649610/can-we-set-style-to-title-tag-in-header#comment98733938_6649610

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is `NO` you cannot do that in any way....you cannot apply any styles to page title, btw you can just blink the titles

[Blinking Titles](http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/title-blink.php)

More Info On CSS Which You Are Using:

If you are declaring something like this

```
title{ color: red; font: 12px tahoma;}
```

You don't need to define any class as you are targeting specific title tag which is only 1 in your whole document

And if you are using `.title` than your CSS should be

```
.title{ color: red; font: 12px tahoma;}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it both ways. Hence I gave it a class="title" .title in CSS. I was reading up on title tags and it said somewhere that it could read a class but not the tag itself. So I listed thing I had tried... I didn't think that if it wouldn't read the tag then it would read a class but I had to try it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah, my rank isn't high enough to do the voting yet. I have a question about the blinking title. I see that it calls up two different messages. Does this effect SEO in any way? I know that titles are one of the first things that a search bot crawls, so I was wondering if it takes any of that away by using the Javascript?

Comment: Makes sense not to enable it: would be a bit confusing when browsing, especially when having many tabs open. As 'cool' as it could maybe be for some few websites.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers are correct, but, you can sort of get different fonts if they are defined in unicode. I don't know how to explore this, but, for example, there's the regularly written word `javascript` and then there's this title I coped from reddit.com/r/javascript source code:  - notice how they are slightly different.

Regular without code delimiters: javascript

Reddits title without code delimiters:

You can copy past these characters anywhere and they are going to look different, because they are technically _different characters. There's a and then there's  - I grabbed this from the javascript word I previously pasted.

I don't know where these characters came from. I don't know how to type them. I don't know where one could copy paste them from.

But it proves an interesting point - any emoji can be used in these titles, you can copy paste from https://www.emojicopy.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the `<title></title>` section **then no you can't style it.**

If you are talking about the title of a page as in a header tag such as h1 or h2 then yes you can style those using normal CSS styling techniques such as

```
.title { color: #1A1A1A }

<h1 class="title">My Awesome Title</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks @ryan but that is not what I am talking about. I was talking about an actual <title></title> tag.

Comment: @absoluteneXus sorry, that was in my answer, added the code tag around the title tags so it shows.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the `<title>` tag, just add "display:block" or "display:inline" to it.

```
title {
    display:block;
    color:red;
    font:12px tahoma, serif;
}
```

that way it should appear inside your page with the same content of the tab on the browser, for instance.

As for the Page Title, i have seen that it is possible to style it, someway. probably with shadow dom.