# Colored characters in HTML title

Tags: css, html

Using Firefox I stumbled upon a page with differently colored characters in the title. How to insert colored characters into a HTML `<title>` tag? What is this standard called?

Update:
Apparently it has something to do with the (UTF?) heart emojis characters. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Different colors]

Instructions on how to insert those can be found [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Heart-on-Facebook). I made a test Facebook post and it really renders hearts of different colors in Firefox title.

Comment: Please screenshot and any styling applied to title tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579477/can-i-give-a-title-tag-a-color-and-different-font

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just made a FB test page and it renders heart characters of different colors in title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Unicode.**](https://home.unicode.org/emoji/about-emoji/) Icon symbols AKA: **Pictographs ☕, Emojis** .

| Symbol | HEX code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ✍ | `&#x270d;` | Pictograph |
| ✍︎ | `&#x270d;&#xfe0e;` | Pictographs as **Standardized Variant** |

To use them in your Title:

```
<title>Hearts &#x1F499;&#x1F49A;&#x1F49B;</title>
```

> Hearts

Don't forget that if you have some transportation website and you used this character ⛟ `&#x26df;` for your **"⛟ Order now!"** button - watch out! Tomorrow it could shine in the competitor's colors — so use the standardized variant: ⛟︎ `&#x26df;&#xfe0e;` - or rather a custom SVG or Font-icon that matches the brand needs.

<sub>PS:</sub>
Don't use `transform: rotate(Ndeg);` ☜ ☝ ☞ ☟  it's just matter of time ;)

- [Unicode.org - Emoji](https://home.unicode.org/emoji/about-emoji/)
- [Unicode.org - Emoji - Reports tr51](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/)
- [Standardized Variants](http://www.unicode.org/Public/7.0.0/ucd/StandardizedVariants.html)
- [Unicode Standards (7.0.0)](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/)
- [the-absolute-minimum-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)
- [Unicode characters generator](http://output.jsbin.com/nonuju/6/)
- [How to prevent Unicode characters from rendering as emoji in HTML from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38452396/383904)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't colored chars... This is emojis :)

You should use some emoji-support plugin, like this:

https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/

In addition, you will need to add emoji dynamically in the title (using jQuery, for example), as you will need to load the library first.

Comment: Close, but it has nothing to do with the link you posted.

Comment: Firefox appears to support those emojis out of the box. If I am correct.

Comment: He can use the css, but he probably will call the css file after <title> tag. Jquery could help to add the emoji to title tag. It's a great solution that works.

Answer (score -2):

The colors are like blinking text you need escape character like \033 or \x1b

PS1='-e ImposterMO@$(pwd)̵t_ '