# Add class to the title to change the color according to the data value of gauge highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Can we add class or change color of the title according to the from and to color values in gauge highcharts

I am working on the following code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        borderWidth: 0,
    },

    title: {
        useHTML: true,
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        floating: false,
        text: '<div style="text-align:center"><span class="gauge-count">80</span><span class="gauge-category-title">mg/L</span></div>'

    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -160,
        endAngle: 160,
        background: null
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: 'transparent',
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickColor: 'transparent',
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 30,
            className: 'red-band'
        }, {
            from: 30,
            to: 60,
            className: 'yellow-band'
        }, {
            from: 60,
            to: 100,
            className: 'green-band'
        }]
    },
    plotOptions: {
        gauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return null;
                },
                y: 80,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: false
            },

        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80]
    }]

}, );
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/qadeershaikh/pen/MRmJwP?editors=0010

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I give a title tag a color and different font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579477/can-i-give-a-title-tag-a-color-and-different-font)

Comment: @MauriceNino the below answer is the one  I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dynamically set the chart's `title` color, you can use `css` method for SVG elements, for example in `render` event function:

```
chart: {
    type: 'gauge',
    borderWidth: 0,
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var value = this.series[0].yData[0],
                color;

            if (value < 30) {
                color = '#DF5353';
            } else if (value < 60) {
                color = '#DDDF0D';
            } else {
                color = '#55BF3B';
            }

            this.title.css({
                color: color
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fj7mLrxa/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#css

Comment: This is what I wanted and I as trying to achieve.  Thanks alot.