# How to apply style to the HTML <title> element?

Tags: html, css, title

My question is simple, I just want to know that is there any way to apply CSS style to HTML  element. Like the following declaration:

```
title{
      color: red;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: not possible, the title is only the part that's shown in your browsers tab. You don't have any control over it.

Comment: You can do it, and theoretically browser could apply them, however they usually don't because titles are usually displayed for example in window titles of the operation system, which don't support styling.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579477/can-i-give-a-title-tag-a-color-and-different-font

Comment: Thanks all of you, I am sure now that it is not possible to modify the style of the title tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way set a style to this element, as it is controlled by the browser and the user. The only thing you can do to the title while viewing the page, is change it, but stay on the same page:

```js
function changeTitle() {
  document.title = "Title Changed!";
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Title has been changed!";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeTitle()">Click Me!</button>

<p id="test"></p>

<p>View source to see the effect!</p>
```

Sorry for the lack of `<title>` styles, but that's the way it is. Maybe in CSS4, they may change it. But, I doubt it.

Comment: I doubt it too, especially as there are major doubts as to whether there will ever be a CSS4 (since CSS now advances each of its modules independently) See [this blog post for more](https://www.rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/09/13/why-there-is-no-css4-explaining-css-levels/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't!
But you can apply style to the header of the browser:

```html
<meta name="theme-color" content="#999999" />
```

Comment: your meta tag didn't work. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: will work on phone, not on laptop.

Comment: is it something like web manifest?

Comment: No. Refer this url and see the difference between the two images: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color