# styling title tag in the head with css or js

Tags: javascript, css, page-title

Is there any way to style the `<title> Page Title </title>` element? For example changing it's font?
I searched a lot, they say it is not possible with CSS.
How about JS? Any jquery plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser allows JS to give the page dynamic behaviour, but changing the font of a window belongs to the OS.
The tab, instead is controlled by the browser but it doesn't interact with the page.

Comment: Since I was looking for a way to change the font of **title** in the browser's tab, your answer best fit my question.  
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. Browser does not allow to do so. Maybe you can push the limit a little using unicode characters.

```
§ × Ì · ¨
```

But that's all.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no way to adjust the style of the title as rendered in the browser's tab bar or title bar. They are not part of the page.

You can style [the `title` element *in the page*](http://jsbin.com/xumejoqoha/1/edit?html,output) however you like.

```
head { display: block; }
title { display: block; font-size: 1.75em; }
```

Comment: Ha, you answered this last time :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649610/can-we-set-style-to-title-tag-in-header

Comment: Thank you Quentin for the answer. actually the code you provided doesn't solve my problem. but it is a general and informative answer.

Comment: @Sattar — You accepted an answer which says the same thing as the first paragraph of this answer. Does that answer not solve your problem either?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just accepted that because I saw it earlier than yours, and the explanation it provided about JS.
I doubt if I can accept two answers, but your answer is accepted too.
thanks buddy!

Answer (score -3):

Hello try it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
               $('title').css('font-size',24+'px');
               $('title').css('display','block');
        });
```

Can you please explanation it more like where are want to use it,because it auto display none,If you tell me where are want to use this, then i am provide full help and also try this code.

CSS

```
title {
    display: block !important;
    color: #f00;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 14px;
}
```

And full code are given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
title {
    display: block !important;
    color: #f00;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 14px;
}
.screen {
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  width: 190px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
 }
 .content {
   width: 168px;
   height: 300px;
   padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
 }
 .screen::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
 }
 .content:hover{ overflow-x:scroll;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="screen">
<p class="content">Pellentesque habitant morbi
  tristique senectus et netus
  et malesuada fames ac turpis
  egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam,
  feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,
  tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu
  libero sit amet quam egestas semper.
  Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo. Aenean ultricies
  mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo
  Pellentesque habitant morbi
    tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis
    egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam,
    feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,
    tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu
    libero sit amet quam egestas semper.
    Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Aenean ultricies
    mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo
    Pellentesque habitant morbi
      tristique senectus et netus
      et malesuada fames ac turpis
      egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam,
      feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,
      tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu
      libero sit amet quam egestas semper.
      Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
      placerat eleifend leo. Aenean ultricies
      mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: while this answer could be a good answer, just posting code without any explaining will not be helpfull