# Is editing the <title> text using css possible?

Tags: html, css

Can't find the answer anywhere, is there a way to edit the `<title>exampletext</title>` using css to give it for example a 'bold' weight or color: red?

Comment: Simple answer: No.

Comment: You can't change title text using CSS

Comment: This link could be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649610/can-we-set-style-to-title-tag-in-header

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, but in js you can edit or modify title itself but no way to apply css sorry

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.title = 'new title';
    });

</script>
```

however you can do something like

```
head { display: block; }
title { display: block; font-size: 200%; font-weight: bold; }
```

but again this wont work excatly as you want

Comment: OP wants to apply styles to title (Not change text inside).

Comment: Does this work for attributes like 'color:'? And if yes, how?

Comment: no, you cant apply any style to title tag not even with js however you can change text of it

Comment: You can add to HTML element `$("p").css("color", "red");`