# Is it possible to use style attribute in <title> tag?

Tags: html, css

How to use `style` attribute in `<title>` tag? Is it possible?

Comment: The title tag is just the text displayed in browser tabs. It’s plain text. What styling are you wanting to add to that?

Comment: @ Martin Bean Need to add background color

Comment: No, and it is not relevant to have style on title tag, it is for the browser,  you can have a fev-icon though which stands out.

Comment: _Need to add background color._ No, you don’t. You can’t style browser tabs. Those titles are just text.

Answer (score 0):

Like most HTML tags, you can style it, but you can't change the way it looks in the browser tabs (since it's plain text). More informations about can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp).

**HTML**

```html
<head>
   <meta ... />
   <meta ... />

   <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
```

**CSS**

```css
title { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The title element has default styling `display: none`. You can overwrite it so it will be shown. However I don't think it's recommended to do that.

This will only work when it's placed in the `body` element. However the `title` element should be placed in the head element. So this styling might not even work in all browsers.

If you want to style the way it looks in the browsers bar / tab then you can not do that in most, if not all, browsers. What you can do is alter the favicon.

```css
title {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<title>test</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please search for any similar questions like that, before you ask.
The question already exists

See the answers from another post:
[Can we set style to title tag in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649610/can-we-set-style-to-title-tag-in-header)