# How to insert content into title tag have content in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there any possibility how to target HTML tag `<title>` in CSS for *content: ""*?
It would be pretty neat to control both the `<h1>` and the title of the page by one attribute.
I've tried something like

```
title::before{
content: "Hello world"
}
```

If this won't be possible, what other solution might be appropriate?
Thanks!

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for that mate, pseudo elements wouldn't work how you're envisioning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add title attribute from css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649610/can-we-set-style-to-title-tag-in-header)

Comment: Voted to reopen as the suggested duplicate was about the title attribute, whereas this question is about the title element.

Comment: You can apply an HTML `class` to the `<title>` and `<h1>` tags. Then you can control both with one block of CSS selector code.

Comment: From an SEO perspective, this is probably not a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

You sure can, in fact, as **all** elements in a HTML document are plain `<tags>` they can be made visible and get `id`, `class`, `style` (inline or style block) or any other selector attribute, whether global or custom. Even `contenteditable` and make them runtime editable (won't work on `<script>`, though).

Below **a snippet** displaying `<title>` with pseudo selectors.

...And if you really want to dig into showing runtime styles, links and javascript check out [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/zYPKEVL) I created some time ago. *Beware, not for beginners*. Hit the bottom/right [show styles] button in the pen and see the magic happen...

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document Title, quite long some we can forse a line break (well, on smaller windows anyway...)</title>

        <style>
            /* Because it is hidden by default */
            head {
                display: block;
            }

            title {
                display: block; /* default hidden too */

                width: 100%;
                min-height : 2rem;
                line-height: 2rem;

                hyphens: auto;

                cursor: pointer; overflow: hidden;
                font-size: larger; text-align: center;

                background-color: hsl(45,100%,50%);
            } 

            title::before { content: 'Before: ' ; font-weight: bold }
            title::after  { content: ' :The End!'; font-weight: bold }
            
            body { background-color: Gainsboro }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Some regular paragraph element</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this work with populating the title in the browser tab? How about in Search Engine Result Pages? They are the more important uses of the `<title>` tag.

Comment: @JonP, you're probably right. However, this is not about SEO (no mention by OP), but more about showing what is possible.  Browser tab would require JS.

Comment: This is kinda cool but I'm fairly sure OP wanted to control the title of the page in the browser tab

Comment: @ZachJensz, debatable, then again, so might OP mentioning `h1`. Gave it some thought before, though. Decided to ignore browser *tab*  for now. Lets give OP time to reply...

Comment: @RenevanderLende My intentions were to control h1 (and possibly other elements) together with the browser tab as you mentioned. So far the name of the page is the same in the title - respectively browser tab, h1 and in the menu. So my idea was to control all of that at once...